# Combined Object with different Materials but Seams are obvious

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, texture-baking, height-map

[image]Blender fans and team,

I have created a building that for its wall, I combined a couple of different materials. I would like to mention that all of these materials, are the same Plaster (or stucco)texture, but each of them has a different decal. 
The materials have colour, roughness, normal and height maps. Additionally, I have merged all the vertices.
But unfortunately, when I render (cycles) the seams between these materials are obvious. Is there anything that I could do, so to erase these seams?

Thank you[image]

Comment: if you mean that the repeat of the pattern is too visible you need to make a repeatable pattern, you can use an image editor to do that (Filter > Other > Offset in Photoshop), is it your problem?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, I don't mean that I have updated the picture to point out what I mean.

Comment: could you please share an object with the same texture (just a cube for example, don't forget to pack the images)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Well, I found out that these edges were created in Substance Painter. The mask makes a weird bevel effect. I texted them to see if they can help me. But if there is any solution to minimise or hide them while I compose my scene, I would have been really happy.